# Why do we specify the interface for the service?

Tags: wsdl, wsdl-2.0

I'm currently learning the WSDL 2.0 specification and examining the example provided by http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20-primer/#basics-service

```
  <interface  name = "reservationInterface" >
    . . .
  </interface>

  <binding name="reservationSOAPBinding" 
          interface="tns:reservationInterface"
        . . . >
    . . .
  </binding>

  <service name="reservationService" 
       interface="tns:reservationInterface">

     <endpoint name="reservationEndpoint" 
               binding="tns:reservationSOAPBinding"
               address ="http://greath.example.com/2004/reservation"/>

  </service>
```

Here you can see that in `service` declaration we have to specify `interface` attribute, though it was already specified in the `binding` declaration. So having binding name - we could resolve the interface name it implements. From my point of view (the person who doesn't know the specification yet) - it's just a data duplication.

The question: what is the `interface` in `service` specified for? Is there any practical reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the WSDL 2.0 specification (WSDL 1.1 is still the de facto way of describing web services) but I think this is actually backwards. The `<service>` needs the `interface` attribute while the one on the `<binding>` is optional.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20-primer/#basics-service (emphasis mine):

> **A WSDL 2.0 service specifies a single interface that the service will support**, and a list of endpoint locations where that service can be accessed. Each endpoint must also reference a previously defined binding to indicate what protocols and transmission formats are to be used at that endpoint. **A service is only permitted to have one interface**.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20-primer/#more-bindings-reusable (emphasis mine):

> A binding can either be reusable (applicable to any interface) or non-reusable (specified for a particular interface). [...] **To define a reusable binding, the binding element simply omits the interface attribute** and omits specifying any operation-specific and fault-specific binding details. Endpoints can later refer to a reusable binding in the same manner as for a non-reusable binding. Thus, **a reusable binding becomes associated with a particular interface when it is referenced from an endpoint, because an endpoint is part of a service, and the service specifies a particular interface that it implements**.

As I understand it, you need the `interface` on the `<service>` to specify which interface is being implemented, while the `interface` on the `<binding>` limits it's usage to that interface only. It seems kinda redundant when both are specified but they are used for different things.